# String equals in Android studio

Tags: java

Was just wondering why I get

> Cannot resolve symbol 'equals'

on the string.equals. Im using andriod studio.

```
public class Transaction {

    String type;
    double amount;

    if(type.equals("Deposit")){


    };


}
```

Comment: You have a missing closing bracket - "
if(type.equals("Deposit"){" - should be "
if(type.equals("Deposit")){"

Comment: Even with the bracket there, still the same error.

Comment: You **must** put your code in a executable block. For example, write your "if" inside a method (instance method). Daniel, i'm afraid your code won't work because it is invalid according to the languaje specs.

Comment: How would I do that, could you show me an example?

Comment: i made you an example!

Comment: The reason you're getting an error is because the if statement isn't inside a method. Java is comprised of methods as it is an Object Oriented Based Programing Language. (OOBPL) Check this link to solve your issue: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write your test in a function like :

```
public class Transaction {

    String type;
    double amount;

    public void testType() {
        if(type.equals("Deposit")) {


        }
    }
}
```